# Deserialising json key-value into Dictionary c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net, deserialization

I have the following JSON in the request body:

```
{
    "tableName": "ApiTestTbl",
    "columnsValues": {
        "test1": "value1",
        "column2": "value2"
    }
}
```

And I have these 2 classes:

```
public class InsertIntoDbEntity 
{
    public string tableName { get; set; }
    public InsertIntoDbColumnsValuesEntity columnsValues { get; set; }
}

public class InsertIntoDbColumnsValuesEntity
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> columnsValues { get; set; }
}
```

And the controller function is the following:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("app/singleinsert")]
public CrudReturnEntity InsertIntoDB(InsertIntoDbEntity entity)
{        
    return null;
}
```

The value of tableName is well assigned "ApiTestTbl", but columnsValues is always null.
I am using a Dictionary because the number of key-value pairs in columnValues is not defined, so I want to store them in a Dictionary for processing.
Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you want your custom `InsertIntoDbColumsValiesEntity` and not just declare the property as a `Dictionary<string, string>` directly? Because the fact that you're forcing another class in there is what is making the default deserialization fail

Comment: Yes I need it this way because I want the columnsValues key pairs to be in a seperate json object and not in the root object such as tableName.

Comment: @Knoop you were right! After I did what you suggested I have now the intended result. I don't know why I complicated things. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As @Knoop suggested in the comments, it's rather straightforward in your case, to have the Dictionary<string,string> directly as a member of your InsertIntoDbEntity model.

However in cases where you do not have this feasibility and have the requirement for a strict structure, following is the way to solve it. We are going to build a custom Json Converter for the inner property, making use of Newtonsoft.Json.

#### Creating a custom JSON converter for inner property

```
public class MyInternalConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if(reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
        {
            JObject item = JObject.Load(reader);

            // You may want to perform any sanity checks you want here

            Dictionary<string, string> blah = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(item.ToString());

            return new InsertIntoDbColumnsValuesEntity
            {
                columnsValues = blah
            };
        }
        return null;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You also need to decorate the property within your model to leverage the custom converter written. This is done as shown below

```
public class InsertIntoDbEntity
{
    public string tableName { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(MyInternalConverter))]
    public InsertIntoDbColumnsValuesEntity columnsValues { get; set; }
}
```

Essentially, the same technique can be leveraged at the property level or class level depending on the need for a custom deserialization.